# Change user picture via services 3

Tags: 7, services, media, users

I'm update user profile data via services 3 but I have a problem with user picture. I send user picture to my web site via services and it works:

```
{"fid":"1078","uri":"http://MyDomain/rest/file/1078"}
```

But how can I pass this "FID" to the user update method ? Which is the correct parameter name ?

Thanks.

M.

Answer (score 1):

The file ID is stored in the  `picture` column of the [users table](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.install/function/user_schema/7)

> Foreign key: {file_managed}.fid of user's picture.

So your payload to the update resource would look something like

```
{
  "uid": "123", 
  "data": { 
    "picture": "1078",
    # rest of user data
  }
}
```

Comment: @keithm It'd make more sense if that column at least had `fid` in it somewhere I guess, but no, it's the `picture` column that stores the user picture file id

Comment: Nope. It does not works.  All other data are correctly updated, but not the image profile. I have tried to add "data...." to { account : .....} but without success

Comment: According to [`_user_resource_definition()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21services%21resources%21user_resource.inc/function/_user_resource_definition/7) the JSON you send should contain 'uid' and 'data' only - there's no 'account' variable involved

Comment: Clive: I have tried in all way without success. All parameters that I pass to update method works, the only with problem is "picture". I have tried to pass the same structure that I get via /user/X.json too, but always without success.

Answer (score 1):

The `fid` you pass there is just ignored. You have to write a bit of code in a module to save the `fid` yourself.

You can find code ready to be copy-pasted here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2471178#comment-9825329

Note: the `picture_upload` field is processed server-side but it won't actually work either because the file upload module looks at `$_FILES` and that'll be empty. The `$user->picture` `fid` will thus be set to 0 (current avatar, if any, will be removed).